# Paypal IPN for E-Cheque not sending mc_fee

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Using Paypal sandbox, when an E-Cheque payment IPN message is sent it doesn't include `mc_fee`:

```
transaction_subject=42%7c6650a562-d533-44aa-8564-0c9c0e7d19b2&txn_type=web_accept&payment_date=10%3a12%3a04+Jun+23%2c+2014+PDT&last_name=Gullen&residence_country=US&pending_reason=echeck&item_name=4+items&payment_gross=53.76&mc_currency=USD&business=payments%40scirra.com&payment_type=echeck&protection_eligibility=Ineligible&verify_sign=AynlJ2zsmflH.74VEfIBZZJsEArxAjNAi0hD7WaaPRn3XedTlWuF7oga&payer_status=verified&test_ipn=1&tax=0.00&payer_email=tom%40scirra.com&txn_id=69591827P76604800&quantity=1&receiver_email=payments%40scirra.com&first_name=Tom&payer_id=N4ZM2MRGFSGG6&receiver_id=PPMVMPWQE975C&item_number=&handling_amount=0.00&payment_status=Pending&shipping=0.00&mc_gross=53.76&custom=42%7c6650a562-d533-44aa-8564-0c9c0e7d19b2&charset=windows-1252&notify_version=3.8&ipn_track_id=6e3b4b535ff63
```

When the fee is showing in the receiving account as $2.40.

Is the `mc_fee` for the e-cheque payment sent when the payment clears?  Does anyone have an example of a cleared E-Check IPN message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the fee will be included with the IPN for the cleared/completed payment.  Here's a sample of a cleared echeck IPN.

```
Array
(
    [mc_gross] => 25.00
    [invoice] => 4145
    [item_mpn1] => 
    [protection_eligibility] => Ineligible
    [item_count_unit1] => 0
    [item_number1] => 20
    [tax] => 0.00
    [payer_id] => WZQB555NMG
    [payment_date] => 08:56:21 Sep 20, 2012 PDT
    [item_tax_rate1] => 0
    [payment_status] => Completed
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [mc_shipping] => 0.00
    [item_tax_rate_double1] => 0.00
    [mc_handling] => 0.00
    [first_name] => Tester
    [mc_fee] => 0.85
    [notify_version] => 3.7
    [echeck_time_processed] => 07:00:23 Sep 25, 2012 PDT
    [custom] => 
    [payer_status] => verified
    [num_cart_items] => 1
    [mc_handling1] => 0.00
    [verify_sign] => AapgbjzZyTSfkmpNOv5lUoTq-NAIA1Troj6rjlQyLdJv8HapgwwIiw4M
    [payer_email] => tester@hey.org
    [mc_shipping1] => 0.00
    [item_style_number1] => 
    [tax1] => 0.00
    [contact_phone] => 972-294-5555
    [item_plu1] => 
    [txn_id] => 9MD93138E1640023P
    [payment_type] => echeck
    [payer_business_name] => Little Elm Friends of the Library
    [last_name] => Deaver
    [item_name1] => USBSwiper Software Only RENTAL Program
    [receiver_email] => testseller@testerseller.com
    [item_isbn1] => 
    [payment_fee] => 0.85
    [quantity1] => 1
    [receiver_id] => M5VR555CSK6
    [txn_type] => cart
    [item_model_number1] => 
    [mc_gross_1] => 25.00
    [mc_currency] => USD
    [item_taxable1] => N
    [residence_country] => US
    [transaction_subject] => USBSwiper.com Web OrderUSBSwiper Software Only RENTAL Program
    [payment_gross] => 25.00
    [ipn_track_id] => 5104f64ac8bd2
)
```